# Добавить ссылку MySql.Data на VisualStudio2015

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

Новичок. Работаю на VisualStudio2015. Недавно столкнулся с проблемой: нужно добавить ссылку на MySql.Data, но поиск её не находит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил с помощью NuGet. Для нескольких компонентов (в том числе и для нужного мне MySql.Data) выдаёт следующее сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Установите из NuGet: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо. Установил. Но я столкнулся с проблемой: при установке MySql.Data он выдаёт сообщение о том, что некоторые ссылки не найдены, в том числе и нужная мне MySql.Data Можно ли как-то это исправить?

Comment: Не понимаю, о чем вы

Comment: @АндрейNOP, секунду

Comment: Лучшее решение: установить VS 2019. В ней встроенный Package Manager для nuget.

Comment: У меня уже NuGet стоял к тому моменту

Answer (score 1):

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/   нажмите на этот ссылку

Product version: 7.0.6 m5  скачивайте и установить
Cледующий шаг открывайте visual studio и запуститьe Windows Forms Application
Потом References  -> Add reference -> Extensions и выбирайте Mysql.data